# How to pack arrays by bitmap selection in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

Supposed we have a

```
wire      [31:0]  vector  [15:0]
```

and a

```
wire      [15:0]  bitmap
```

The bitmap is a one hot selector. If

```
bitmap == 16'b1101,
```

then

```
Output = {412'h0, vector[3],vector[2],vector[0]}.
```

How could you do this in Verilog with timing applicable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you clarify your statements about 'timing' and 'one-hot' selector?

Comment: `16'b0000_0000_0000_1101` is certainly not a one hot selection. And what is the width of Output?

Comment: @dave_59 Thanks for reply, one hot here means each 1 in  bitmap select the corresponding output to be packed. If bitmap is 1011, the 0th, 1st and 3rd vectors are going to be packed, and all MSB should be 0. In this case, there should be 512 - 3*32 = 412'h0

Comment: @Serge Thanks for reply, timing means the code should not have obvious timing violation after synthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that output's total size is 512 bits (32 bits of vector * 16 bits of bitmap logic with one-hot encoding) one of the ways to write the verilog code such that you get output as "{vector[15], vector[14],....,vector[1], vector[0]}" is by writing 16 always blocks with a 32-bit output logic from each always block such that these always blocks should have their outputs controlled via bitmap logic / one-hot encoding.

An example of 4 such always blocks is given below:

```
always @ ( * ) begin
  if (reset) begin
    output_0  = 0;
  end
  else if (bitmap[0]) begin
    output_0  = vector[0];
  end
  else  begin
    output_0  = output_0;
  end
end

always @ ( * ) begin
  if (reset) begin
    output_1  = 0;
  end
  else if (bitmap[1]) begin
    output_1  = vector[1];
  end
  else  begin
    output_1  = output_1;
  end
end

always @ ( * ) begin
  if (reset) begin
    output_2  = 0;
  end
  else if (bitmap[2]) begin
    output_2  = vector[2];
  end
  else  begin
    output_2  = output_2;
  end
end

always @ ( * ) begin
  if (reset) begin
    output_3  = 0;
  end
  else if (bitmap[3]) begin
    output_3  = vector[3];
  end
  else  begin
    output_3  = output_3;
  end
end
```

Write 16 such blocks in total for the 16 one-hot encoding given via bitmap and then write output via 'assign' statement and wire declaration as shown below:

```
wire [511:0] Main_output;

assign Main_output = {output_15, output_14, output_13, output_12, output_11, output_10, output_9, output_8,
                      output_7, output_6, output_5, output_4, output_3, output_2, output_1, output_0};
```

Alternative way of getting output at clock cycle will be using an always block and register declaration as follows:

```
reg [511:0]  Main_output;

always @ (posedge clock)
   begin
      Main_output <= {output_15, output_14, output_13, output_12, output_11, output_10, output_9, output_8,
                          output_7, output_6, output_5, output_4, output_3, output_2, output_1, output_0};
   end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. In my case, if the bitmap[n]=0, the corresponding output_n is not supposed to be 0. But should be dropped. For example: bitmap == 16'b1101, Output = {412'h0, vector[3],vector[2],vector[0]}. See there is no gap for the ones which bitmap is 0